# How to change date field format in elasticsearch in existing indexes as well

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

So I have quite lots of documents/indexes , in elastic search .

They have a mapping for a date field , and its format is "epoch_millis" .
I have been asked to change its format to some readable format , because when debugging and querying directly on kibaana es.

This epoch millis is not readable . so have been asked to use a readable format .
I get it that i can use format "yyyy-MM-dd" something like this , but how to change in existing documents.
From what i see i have few options :
I can create new field with readable date format , (but again how to add it to existing indexes )
I can Reindex the document , but again It may involve downtime .

Can anyone sugggest me the best option to go around here?
And for FYI , i dont have just one field , here , i have about 8 date type fields , whose format needs to be changed.

Can I do something where , while querying on es , i simply get to see the readable format on date fields , so we don't have to change stuff in mapping at all. ??

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

You can not change the values in a field without:

- Update by query
- Re indexing

But you could leverage the runtime fields.

## Solution

### Runtime fields

What are they:

Created on-the-fly fields during queries without altering index mapping. They are great for dynamic data transformations and calculations.

BUT: They're temporary, and can impact query performance.

Please find below an example on how to use it for you use case.

```json
PUT 77140157
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp":{
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT /77140157/_doc/1
{
  "@timestamp": 1695197861930
}

GET 77140157/_search
{
  "fields": [
    "formated_date"
  ], 
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "formated_date": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "script": {
        "source": """
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = doc['@timestamp'].value;
          def formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        emit(zonedDateTime.format(formatter));
          """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Giving you

```json
{
  "took": 22,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "77140157",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "@timestamp": 1695197861930
        },
        "fields": {
          "formated_date": [
            "2023-09-20 08:17:41"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I am afriad my boss , will like to use this query while searching , for its shear size. and complexity, only if there was another way , in settings etc ? or somewhere , where it returned the date in a format , other than its indexed format . a format which we could set somewhere?

Comment: I am not understanding you perfectly. But I understand you are afraid of the overhead the runtime fields have ? I am afraid I can't think of another way, reindex or runtime fields.

Comment: So i have come across another thing here , scripted fields. i have created a scripted field which is working fine. and converting the epoch to readable format using pain , and is working fine in discover section of kibaana. but it is not coming in response when i hit get request in kibaana , dev-tools . Any idea here? something i could be missing?

Comment: also i dont mind overhead of run time fields , as i dont believe it to behuge . but downtime in case of reindexing is something i am not sure about . also is it possible to declare run time fields , without having to insert it in search query always ? like you have done above . it would be uncomfortable to always type a script while running search query.

Comment: I'll let you dig on runtime fields but you can declare a runtime field at the index level, inside the index settings/mapping. Scripted fields are deprecated so you should move away from those.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime-mapping-fields.html